# dispatch_async understanding the execution order

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch-async

I have two API calls as follows :

```
-(void) doTask1{ 

    dispatch_async(queueSerial, ^{ //B1

     [fileObj setFileInfo:file]; 

    });
}

-(void) doTask2{ 

    dispatch_async(queueSerial, ^{ //B2

        [fileObj getFileInfo:fileName completion:^(NSError *error) {
            dispatch_async(queueSerial2, ^{
                //completion work C1
            });
         }]

    });
}
```

Now, my question is, from what I already understand by reading about GCD, if a process calls `doTask1` and immediately after calls `doTask2`, it will result in both of them being queued and `B1` ahead `B2`.

However, does is ensure that `B1` is fully executed before `B2` starts executing? Because the file updated by `B1` is used by `B2`.

If `B2` starts to execute before `B1` is fully finished, it might result in some issues.

Or is it better to do

```
-(void) doTask1{ 
    dispatch_sync(queueSerial, ^{B1});
}

-(void) doTask2{ 
    dispatch_sync(queueSerial, ^{B2});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `queueSerial` really is a serial queue, then B1 will complete before B2 begins.  There are no guarantees concerning the relationship between those and whatever called the `doTaskN` methods...that would be affected by the `_sync` modification.

If B1 or B2 do any dispatching themselves, that's also not controlled by the serialization.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have edited my question to add more details about the code. The thing that I don't understand is, your comment about "There is no guarantees concerning to the relationship between those" What does this mean?

Comment: I mean that, in the async case, whatever code calls doTask1(), doTask2() may have gone on to do various other operations before the dispatched work is complete.  In the sync case, the caller also stalls until your serial queue operations finish.

Comment: I see . I understand this part.  If B2 is dispatching it's completion handler to a different queue, is it possible for this completion block to be executed before B1 has finished? Is there a way to make sure this won't happen and that the completion block in B2 waits until B1 is finished?

Comment: It won't happen because the completion handler doesn't fire until after `getFileInfo` and `getFileInfo` is behind `setFileInfo` on the same serial queue.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. What happens if  `getFileInfo` and `setFileInfo` are asynchronous methods? Will this affect the outcome?

Comment: It will definitely affect the outcome, and how it does so depends on exactly how they become async.

Comment: I modified my original question from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42403595/forcing-the-order-of-execution-using-dispatch-sync) to be a bit cleaner and precise. Would you be able to help me figure out this one?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a serial queue your task will be finished in the same order (first in first out), but if you use concurrent you won't have any guaranty of the order that they finish.

```
-(void) doTask1{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
    //your code
    });
}

-(void) doTask2{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
    //your code
    });
}
```

Here are a great explanation of GCD and NSOperation for concurrency: https://www.appcoda.com/ios-concurrency/

You need to be sure that both task are send to the same queue.

Update:
Another approach is to use NSOperation because you can set a dependency between task to make sure one is completed before start the other one.

Answer (score 0):

If the task, B1, which was dispatched to the serial queue, is not initiating anything asynchronous itself, then you're assured that B1 will finish before B2 starts. But if B1 is doing anything asynchronous (e.g., a network request, etc.), then you need other patterns to make sure that B2 doesn't start until B1's asynchronous task finishes (e.g. implement your own completion handlers, use `dispatch_group_notify`, wrap the tasks in asynchronous custom `NSOperation` subclasses, etc.).

Comment: I modified the question a bit more and created a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42403595/forcing-the-order-of-execution-using-dispatch-sync). Would you be able to help me figure out this one? I am not sure how I should use the `dispatch_group_notify` call here since they are 2 different methods